# Changing an editable JqGrid row back to Uneditable without using cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a question regarding jqgrid. In order to edit a row in my grid you have to select the edit button that is using the action formatter. This makes almost the whole row editable.

My question is that if the user clicks another rows edit button, instead of the cancel or submit button on the currently editable row, is there a way to return the first editable row to a non-editable state while leaving the newly selected row editable?

Here's the grid if you want to check is out. Rather large amount of code. The data is passed to the grid through a function. This is part of a large MVC app. The data is in json format.

Suggestions on which direction to go would be greatly appreciated.

```
 grid.jqGrid({
        datatype: "local",
        data: gridData,
        colNames: ['Action', 'ID', 'Center', 'DBA', 'Check Number', 'Received Date', 'Check Amount', 'Unposted Amount', 'Posted Amount', 'Comments', 'Check Date', 'Received By', 'Withdrawn By', 'Withdrawal Date', 'Witness', 'Is Posted?', 'Is NSed?', 'Refunded Amount', 'Batch Number'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 55, align: 'center', sortable: false, formatter: 'actions',
                formatoptions: { keys: true,
                    delbutton: false,
                    extraparam: { CheckLogId: getChecklogId, IsPosted: getIsPosted, CheckAmountPosted: getCheckAmountPosted, BatchNumberSequence: getBatchSeqNumber, IsNSed: getIsNSed },
                    afterSave: afterEditSave,
                    onSuccess: afterOnSuccess,
                    afterRestore: function (rowid) {
                        var acc_list = getAccountDBAOnCenter(last_center);
                        grid.setColProp('AccountId', { editoptions: { value: convertToSelectList(acc_list)} });
                        grid.trigger('reloadGrid');

                        if (!isCurrentUserAdmin) {
                            grid.setCell(rowid, 2, '', { 'visibility': 'visible' });
                        }
                    },                      
                    onEdit: function (rowid) {
                        edit_row_id = rowid;
                        grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
                        if (grid.getCell(rowid, 'IsPosted') == true) {
                            var checkAmountInput = '#' + rowid + '_CheckAmount';
                            $(checkAmountInput).prop("disabled", true);
                        }
                        else {
                            var checkAmountInput = '#' + rowid + '_CheckAmount';
                            $(checkAmountInput).prop("disabled", false);
                        }
                        if (!isCurrentUserAdmin) {
                            grid.setCell(rowid, 'CenterId', '', { 'visibility': 'hidden' });                                
                        }                           
                        checklog_id = grid.getCell(rowid, 'CheckLogId');
                        batch_sql_num = grid.getCell(rowid, 'BatchNumberSequence');
                        is_posted = grid.getCell(rowid, 'IsPosted');
                        check_amount_posted = grid.getCell(rowid, 'CheckAmountPosted');
                        check_amount_refunded = grid.getCell(rowid, 'CheckAmountRefunded');
                        is_nsed = grid.getCell(rowid, 'IsNSed');
                        batch_sql_num = batch_sql_num == '' ? '-' : batch_sql_num;
                    }
                }
            },
            { name: "CheckLogId", index: "CheckLogId", width: 40, align: "center", editable: false, hidden: true, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, search: false },
            { name: "CenterId", index: "CenterId", width: 200, align: "left", editrules: { required: true },
                editable: true,
                formatter: 'select',
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: {
                    value: getSelectList(center_list),
                    style: 'width:190px',
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        var center_id = $(elem).val();
                        if (center_id == '') {
                            center_id = $("#center_id").val();
                        }
                        last_center = center_id;
                        var list_data = getAccountDBAOnCenter(center_id);
                        grid.setColProp('AccountId', { editoptions: { value: convertToSelectList(list_data)} });
                    },
                    dataEvents: [
                            {
                                type: 'change',
                                fn: function (e) {
                                    resetAccountDBAValues();
                                    var center_id = parseInt($(e.target).val(), 10);
                                    var dba_select_list = getAccountDBAOnCenter(center_id);

                                    var newOptions = '';
                                    $.each(dba_select_list, function (i, dbaRecord) {
                                        newOptions += '<option role="option" value="' +
                                                    dbaRecord.AccountId + '">' +
                                                    dbaRecord.DBAName + '</option>';
                                    });
                                    if ($(e.target).is('.FormElement')) {
                                        var form = $(e.target).closest('form.FormGrid');
                                        var acccountElm = form.find("select#AccountId.FormElement");
                                        acccountElm.removeAttr("disabled");
                                        acccountElm.html(newOptions);
                                    } else {
                                        var row = $(e.target).closest('tr.jqgrow');
                                        var rowId = row.attr('id');
                                        $("select#" + rowId + "_AccountId", row[0]).html(newOptions);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                }, search: false
            },
            { name: "AccountId", index: "AccountId", width: 200, align: "left", formatter: 'select', editable: true, editrules: { required: true },
                edittype: 'select',
                editoptions: { value: dba_select_list_json, style: 'width:190px' },
                search: true
            },
            { name: "CheckNumber", index: "CheckNumber", width: 110, align: "left", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10, style: 'width:90px' }, search: false },
            { name: "ReceivedDate", index: "ReceivedDate", width: 100, align: "center", datefmt: 'm/d/yy', formatter: jsonDateFormatter, editable: true, editrules: { date: false, required: true, custom: true, custom_func: dateValidate }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10, style: 'width:90px', dataInit: function (element) { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true }) } }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckAmount", index: "CheckAmount", width: 110, align: "left", formatter: 'currency', editable: true, editrules: { required: true, number: true }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10, style: 'width:90px' }, formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$" }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckAmountUnposted", index: "CheckAmountUnposted", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: uPostFormatter, editable: false, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$" }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckAmountPosted", index: "CheckAmountPosted", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: 'currency', editable: false, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$" }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckDescription", index: "CheckDescription", width: 180, align: "left", editable: true, editrules: { required: false }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 100, maxlength: 100, style: 'width:200px' }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckDate", index: "CheckDate", width: 100, align: "center", formatter: jsonDateFormatter, editable: true, editrules: { required: true, custom: true, custom_func: checkValidation }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10, style: 'width:90px', dataInit: function (element) { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true }) } } },
            { name: "ReceivedBy", index: "ReceivedBy", width: 120, align: "left", editable: true, editrules: { required: true }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 15, maxlength: 15, style: 'width:110px' }, search: false },
            { name: "WithdrawnBy", index: "WithdrawnBy", width: 120, align: "left", editable: true, editrules: { required: false }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 15, maxlength: 15, style: 'width:110px' }, search: false },
            { name: "WithdrawnDate", index: "WithdrawnDate", width: 100, align: "center", datefmt: 'm/d/yy', formatter: jsonDateFormatter, editable: true, editrules: { date: false, required: false, custom: true, custom_func: dateValidate }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 10, maxlength: 10, style: 'width:90px', dataInit: function (element) { $(element).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'm/d/yy', changeYear: true, changeMonth: true }) } }, search: false },
            { name: "WitnessedBy", index: "WitnessedBy", width: 120, align: "left", editable: true, editrules: { required: false }, edittype: 'text', editoptions: { size: 15, maxlength: 15, style: 'width:110px' }, search: false },
            { name: "IsPosted", index: "IsPosted", width: 75, align: "center", editable: false, formatter: booleanFormatter, unformat: booleanUnFormatter, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, search: false },
            { name: "IsNSed", index: "IsNSed", width: 75, align: "center", editable: false, formatter: booleanFormatter, unformat: booleanUnFormatter, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, search: false },
            { name: "CheckAmountRefunded", index: "CheckAmountRefunded", width: 120, align: "center", formatter: 'currency', editable: false, editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true }, formatoptions: { decimalSeparator: ".", thousandsSeparator: ",", decimalPlaces: 2, prefix: "$" }, search: false },
            { name: "BatchNumberSequence", index: "BatchNumberSequence", width: 120, align: "left", editable: false, edittype: 'text', search: false }
        ],
        pager: '#checklog-table-pager',
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [25, 50, 75, 100, 1000000],
        gridview: true,
        rownumbers: false,
        ignoreCase: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        width: 1040,
        height: 400,
        autowidth: false,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        scrolling: true,
        loadonce: false,
        editurl: '/Payment/SaveChecklog',
        loadComplete: loadGridComplete,
        ondblClickRow: function (rowid, iRow, iCol, e) {
            if (grid.getCell(rowid, 'IsNSed') == false) {
                if (showPaymentCallBack) {
                    showPaymentCallBack(rowid);
                }
            }
        }
    }).jqGrid('navGrid', '#checklog-table-pager',
        { add: true, edit: false, del: false },
        {},
        {
            caption: 'Add',
            recreateForm: true,
            mtype: "post",
            width: 520,
            addCaption: "Add Check",
            reloadAfterSubmit: true,
            closeAfterAdd: true,
            bSubmit: "Save",
            onclickSubmit: beforeAdd,
            afterSubmit: addComplete,
            beforeShowForm: beforeShowAdd
        },
        {},
        { multipleSearch: true, overlay: false }
    ).navButtonAdd("#checklog-table-pager", {
        caption: 'Export',
        title: 'Export to Excel',
        buttonicon: 'ui-icon-extlink',
        onClickButton: function () {
            var fileName = 'checklog_for_center_' + center_id + '.xls';
            var dataUrl = 'PaymentService/GetCheckLog';
            var searchParameters = getCheckLogIds();

            $("#checklog-table").jqGrid('excelExport', { url: '/Spreadsheet/Index?fileName=' + fileName + '&dataUrl=' + dataUrl + '&filter=' + searchParameters });
        }
    });


    $("#checklog-table-pager table.navtable tbody tr").append(
            '<td><div><input type="checkbox" class="searchClosedBox" id="navSearchClosedBox"/>NLO Deal</div></td>');
    $(".searchClosedBox").change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            search_closed = true;
            var acc_list = getAccountDBAOnCenter($("#center_id").val());
            dba_select_list_json = acc_list;
            dba_list = acc_list;
            grid.setColProp('AccountId', { editoptions: { value: convertToSelectList(acc_list)} });
            grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
        else {
            search_closed = false;
            var acc_list = getAccountDBAOnCenter($("#center_id").val());
            dba_select_list_json = acc_list;
            dba_list = acc_list;
            grid.setColProp('AccountId', { editoptions: { value: convertToSelectList(acc_list)} });
            grid.trigger('reloadGrid');
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

//Set the current row to false

```
grid.editRow(current_row_id, false);
```

// Set the new row to editable

```
grid.editRow(new_row_id, true);
```

..
or on everytime you select a row, you can add a flag. 
and then disable all rows with that flag when you click.

```
$cur_row.on("click", function(){
// Select all rows's with that flag, disable them and remove flag.
// Add Flag Class to this 
// Then enable this one only.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Dietrich for your answer. I tried using `grid.editRow(lastSel, false);` in my onEdit for action and it didn't work. I have also tried `grid.jqgrid('restoreRow', lastSel)` in the same place with limited success. restoreRow will reset the previous selected row to to non-editable but the action buttons don't revert back to the edit button, they remain as the save an cancel buttons. Any ideas how to change them back? As always any help is greatly appreciated.